# Keycloak Admin Client within Quarkus - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, keycloak, resteasy, quarkus

I'm writing a suite of microservices using [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io).  These services will be protected using [Quarkus' Keycloak extension](https://www.keycloak.org/extensions.html).  That interaction works great and without problem.  Now I'm trying to add functionality to my microservices that will essentially broker communication with Keycloak and allow me to create users/groups/roles programmatically using the [Keycloak](https://keycloak.org) admin client.  I've added the Keycloak admin client dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${version.keycloak}</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code also compiles with no problem.  However, when I run it and attempt to, for example, get a list of users within my Keycloak realm, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient, but class was expected
```

I've implemented functionality like this before in other projects, but never one that uses Quarkus as its underlying implementation framework.  So, my guess is it has something to do with that.  But I've never seen an error like this.  Can anyone give me some insight into how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` is thrown because `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient` has been changed from class to interface since Resteasy version 4.0.

- [ResteasyClient.java in version 3.9](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/3.9/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClient.java)
- [ResteasyClient.java in version 4.0](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/4.0/resteasy-client-api/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClient.java)

So, you should use Resteasy version 3.x.

Comment: I'm not explicitly including Resteasy.  I'm using Quarkus, which builds/bundles its own Resteasy versions.  The standard Keycloak-Quarkus client works with no problem.  The admin client is what fails.

Comment: Your admin client should use Resteasy 3 instead of sharing Resteasy 4 with the Keycloak-Quarkus client.

Comment: According to Keycloak's pom.xml file for v6.0.1, they're using Resteasy 3.6.3, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Probably, Resteasy libraries are not provided for your admin client because of [this problem](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2009). So you may be able to fix your problem by adding some dependencies of Resteasy 3.