# Issue in creating Keycloak object in quarkus application

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

While working with keycloak [Java Distribution 8.0.0 API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/8.0/javadocs/index.html) and quarkus I have an issue in creating Keycloak objects.

dependencies list

```
<properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.0.0.CR2</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.0.0.CR2</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
...

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8181/auth";
    String realmId = "master";
    String clientId = "admin-cli";
    KeycloakClient client = new KeycloakClient(serverUrl, realmId, clientId);
    Keycloak kc = client.getKeycloak("adminuser", "adminpassword");
    RealmResource realmResource = kc.realm("keycloak-client");
    UsersResource userRessource = realmResource.users();
    if (userRessource != null) {
        System.out.println("Count: " + userRessource.count());
    } else {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```

keycloak client class

```
public Keycloak getKeycloak(final String username, final String password) {
    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Client to ResteasyClient
    ResteasyClient resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10)
            .register(new CustomJacksonProvider()).build();

    return KeycloakBuilder.builder().serverUrl(this.serverUrl).realm(this.realmId).username(username)
            .password(password).clientId(this.clientId).resteasyClient(resteasyClient).build();
}
```

I came to know that the issue was caused due to `keycloak-admin-client` which still use ResteasyClient as a Class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58065789/12200758) so i changed my dependency list to the following.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now the Main method working fine but I got another error.

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.resteasy.server.common.deployment.ResteasyServerCommonProcessor#build threw an exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

I want to know that is that possible to work quarkus and keycloak-admin alongside with current version. else there any workaround possible.

Thanks